# SQL queries related to join

Tags: sql, join

There are three tables -

```
employee (emp_id, emp_name)
department (emp_id, emp_dept)
salary (emp_id, emp_sal)
```

I have to find out maximum salary from each department.
Need following columns in output  -

```
emp_id, emp_name, emp_sal, emp_dept
```

Note - 
emp_id is primary key.
In output, emp_sal should be the maximum salary of the department.

Comment: please show us what you tried.

Answer (score -1):

I have put sample data with the query below. I have tested this in SQL Server

```
create table #dept(emp_id int, emp_dept varchar(30))
create table #emp(emp_id int, emp_name varchar(30))
create table #salary(emp_id int, salary int)

insert into #dept values(1,'HR'), (2,'HR'), (3,'Finance')
insert into #emp values (1, 'Venkat'), (2,'raman'), (3, 'Murugan')
insert into #salary values(1, 5000), (2, 10000), (3, 20000)

select emp_dept, emp_id, emp_name
from
(
select d.emp_dept,d.emp_id, e.emp_name, Row_Number() over (partition by d.emp_dept order by s.salary desc) as rnk
from #Dept AS d
LEFT JOIN #Salary AS s
ON d.emp_id = s.emp_id
LEFT JOIN #emp AS e
ON d.emp_id = e.emp_id
) as t
where rnk = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Always try to fetch some data first using simple query and then just make it filter one by one as you want data from that query, so you get a clear idea. Also try below query.

```
SELECT emp_id, emp_name, emp_dept, max(emp_sal) from (SELECT emp_id, emp_name, emp_dept, emp_sal from salary inner join department on salary.emp_id = department.emp_id inner join employee on salary.emp_id = employee.emp_id ) group by emp_dept
```

Also see this link.
[SELECT rows with MAX(Column value), DISTINCT by another column](https://tableplus.io/blog/2018/05/mysql-select-row-max-value-distinct-bu-other-column.html)

Answer (score -2):

Try the below query:

```
   select max(emp_salary), emp_dept  from department d join salary s on d.emp_id = s.emp_id group by emp_dept
```

Comment: Employee table has not been used. I also need emp_id and emp_name in output.